# How to set 'max' value in <input> tag in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

Can I set 'max' value in

```
            <input type="number" step="10" min="10"
                   th:max=""
                   th:field="*{coins}" required>
```

with variable created in ?

```
        <script>
            var wallet = [[${session.student.wallet}]];
            var price = [[${item.itemCost}]];
            var lowerValue = Math.min(wallet, price);
        </script>
```

The problem is to assign to 'max' the smaller of the values visible in .

Answer (score 1):

If you give your input an `id` attribute like (<input id="my-input"...), then it should be as simple as:
`document.getElementById("my-input").setAttribute("max", myCalculatedValue)`;

```js
let
  wallet = 50.00,
  price = 42.00;
const myCalculatedValue = Math.min(wallet, price);

const myInput = document.getElementById("my-input");
myInput.setAttribute("max", myCalculatedValue);
```

```html
<input id="my-input" type="number" step="10" min="10" />
```

Comment: Could you tell me where should i call this function to set the value?

   <script>
    var wallet = [[${session.student.wallet}]];
    var price = [[${item.itemCost}]];
    var lowerValue = Math.min(wallet, price);
    var element = document.getElementsByName("coinsRequired");

    function setLowerValue() {
     element.setAttribute("name", lowerValue);
    }
   </script>

Comment: See the code snippet in the answer. (Note that the behavior when `max` is set to a smaller value than `min` -- at least for me in Chrome -- seems to be that the range is preserved with the low 'max' value replacing 'min', and vice versa.)

Answer (score 0):

```js
//default the max to 99
document.getElementById("yourinput").max = 99;

// setMax gets triggered by the button's `onclick` attribute
function setMax() {
   let max = document.getElementById("yourmax").value;
   document.getElementById("yourinput").max = max;
}
```

```html
<!-- Note that I gave your elements IDs so JS can reference them -->
Default <b>max=99</b> got set when page loaded. Try it below.<br/>
Set max here: <input id="yourmax" value="10"><br/>
Click this button to apply your NEW max: <button onclick="setMax()">Set Max</button></br>
Max gets set on this input: <input id="yourinput" type="number" min="0" style="width:50px;">
```

Comment: Ok but is it possible to assign a value automatically, without clicking any button?

Comment: Yes. Any time you execute `document.getElementById("yourinput").max = whatever_your_max_is;`, the property will be set. So you can execute it when the page first loads, or really anywhere you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with just Thymeleaf.

```
<input type="number"
       step="10" min="10"
       th:max="${T(Math).max(session.student.wallet, item.itemCost)}"
       th:field="*{coins}"
       required>
```